# Java Servlet and JDBC for SQL Server database

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, servlets, jdbc

I have created the JDBCSQl.java, which is basically get one value from database. As standalone it is working fine.

When I call this class within another Servlet Java programming, null value is getting returned.

I've checked the trace log of database, it is not querying a statement at all.

I am getting the error below, when i execute. Both JDBCSQl.java and Servlet.java exists in in a single package of project.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at ValCred.UserIDandPasswordCheck.dbConnect(UserIDandPasswordCheck.java:27)
    at ValCred.CredCheck.doGet(CredCheck.java:31)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
null
```

Thanks
Siddu

Comment: Do you have the `SQLServerDriver` in your classpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add sql server jdbc jar in your web apps lib folder and then try.

Comment: As I said, I am able to trigger jdbc.java as standalone within same package. I have already added SQL drivers to build configuration

Comment: @user2087798 You may have added it to the build config, but it is clearly not ending up in your web application.

Comment: Yes It is there in build config. I am able to execute from normal java class (non servlet java program)

Comment: @user2087798, Please try putting the jar in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.